# No estoy recibiendo los datos de una base de datos a través de ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#enviar").click(function() {

    var datos = {
      nombre:$("#usuario").val(),
      password:$("#password").val()
    }
//peticion ajax
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../informacion-php",
        data: datos,
        dataType: "jason",
        success: function (e) {  
          if (e == "si"){
            $("#hidden").html("usted esta registrado");
          }else{
             $("#hidden").html("usted no esta registrado");
          }

        }
      });

      return false;  
  });     
});
```

Comment: Que no debería ser `informacion.php` y `json` en lugar de `jason`?

Comment: La url de la petición ajax no tiene ninguna extensión.

Comment: Bueno , también el $("#hidden")  da que pensar que tampoco muestras el contenido. Como sugerencia, utiliza nombres que ayuden o indiquen algún propósito. Aquí el #hidden es como decir venga lo que venga no muestres nada. La verdad que si utilizas este tipo de nombres tampoco te van a ayudar mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dicen en los comentarios, la `url` que pones no tiene extensión de archivo, por ejemplo `.php`. También el `dataType` es incorrecto, en lugar de `jason` es `json`, un formato de texto sencillo para el intercambio de datos.

Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#enviar").click(function() {

    var datos = {
      nombre:$("#usuario").val(),
      password:$("#password").val()
    }
//peticion ajax
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../informacion.php", //Aqui estaba el error de la extensión de archivo
        data: datos,
        dataType: "json", // Aquí estaba el error del tipo de datos
        success: function (e) {  
          if (e == "si"){
            $("#hidden").html("usted esta registrado");
          }else{
             $("#hidden").html("usted no esta registrado");
          }

        }
      });

      return false;  
  });     
});
```